# beamer header takes too much space

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

The header with the table of contents takes up too much vertical space and crowds out my slides. I'd like to retain the ToC headers but turn them into two-column displays or something like that, in order to regain space. How does one do that?

[image]

Comment: you could try a different `theme`, but more importantly remember that the `\section` command takes an *optional* argument that will be displayed in the `toc`; for example: `\section[short]{long long long long title}`

Comment: @cmhughes But if I were to shorten the titles (thanks for the tip, btw, didn't know I could!) I'd be saving horizontal space, whereas it's vertical space I'm concerned about. Any particular theme you can suggest, anyway?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, and ended up restructuring my presentation slightly. Instead of eight sections (in one implicit part), I made two parts, one with six sections, and the other with two.

Comment: well, the manual will give you the definitive guide, but for what it's worth I like the `Dresden` theme :) it gives you a *horizontal* `toc`, not `vertical`. I think it's very important to remember that a presentation is *very* different from a regular document- if your audience sees an epic `toc` that has too many entries, they might be a little put off- restructuring (as @MikeRenfro suggests) is almost certainly the best way forward

Comment: @MikeRenfro: Thanks, I love the idea but it turns out that beamer doesn't automatically put parts into its TOC. I found some workarounds in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tableofcontents-from-part-commands-in-beamer but it's quite a mess. Perhaps there is a theme that handles the parts properly?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47939/beamer-with-warsaw-theme-two-column-navigation)